# Validating inclusion in available locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a database field on my `Company` mode which specifies a company's locale. I want to validate the value of it to be contained in the available locales of `I18n`, and I found the inclusion validation of Rails to fit this task.

But when I use

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :locale, inclusion: { in: I18n.available_locales.map { |l| l.to_s } }
end
```

<sub>(the `map` call is because `I18n.available_locales` returns an array of symbols, not strings, so we need to convert them here)</sub>

the locale `de`, which is available when I call `I18n.available_locales` from the Rails console, is **not valid**. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `I18n.available_locales` is evaluated once, when the `Company` class is loaded. Apparently, not all locales are available at that time. What you need to do is to call `available_locales` dynamically, and you can do it with a *proc*:

```
validates :locale, inclusion: { in: proc { I18n.available_locales.map { |l| l.to_s } }
```

This will be evaluated on runtime, and all your locales will be available.

Comment: You could use `map(&:to_s)` instead of `map { |l| l.to_s }`.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I didn't know about that syntax back then.